# Fonts do not load the first time

Tags: angular, nginx, fonts

I have an angular app with my own fonts. Everything works perfectly fine locally, but when it's deployed, fonts do not load the first time and the status is in 'pending' state all the time until I reload the page - from now on, fonts are rendered properly (if I caching is enabled). 
What might cause that?

Comment: have you tried making a [mcve] first, to see at what point the problem "goes away"?

Comment: it turned out to be missing mime type